# I want to use MVC form with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I have a html form and there is inputs when I changed radiobuttons. These radiobuttons have validations for empty case. For example I checked invoiceTypePerson and 
    fill its input and then click submit button but form doesn't submit because of other radiobutton's input is empty. I want to submit them independent with each other. 
    How can I do it? There are my codes below.

```
<div class="inputs">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.InvoiceType, InvoiceType.Person, new { id = "invoiceTypePerson" })
    <label for="invoiceTypePerson" class="companyType">@T("RadioButton1")</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.InvoiceType, InvoiceType.Company, new { id = "invoiceTypeCompany" })
    <label for="invoiceTypeCompany" class="companyType">@T("RadioButton2")</label>
</div>

<div class="inputs sirket">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TaxOffice, new { @class = "text-box single-line", required = "required" })
    @Html.RequiredHint()
    <span class="taxD"></span>
</div>

<div class="inputs sahis">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TcNumber, new { @class = "text-box single-line", required = "required" })
    @Html.RequiredHint()
    <span class="tc"></span>
</div>

<button class="add-address-button"></button>

if($("input[id='invoiceTypePerson']").is(":checked")){
    $('.add-address-button').click(function(){
            var tc = $('input[id*="Address_TcNumber"]').attr('value');
            if (!tc) {
                $("span.tc").html('TC is required');
                return false;
            }
            else if(tc){
                $("span.tc").html('');
            }

            var taxoffice = $('input[id*="Address_TaxOffice"]').attr('value');
            if (!taxoffice) {
                $("span.taxD").html('Taxoffice is required');
                return false;
            }
            else if(tc){
                $("span.taxD").html('');
            }           
    });
}
```

Comment: As your form is constructed now, the user could select both Person and Company. If the radio button values are mutually exclusive, they should have the same name so that the user can select Person or Company, but not both.

Comment: your question is not clear can you reword it a little bit I didnt get it

Comment: Where is your form? When is this sentence being located?: `if($("input[id='invoiceTypePerson']").is(":checked")){` (is it on document ready or where? Please be more specific.